# Structure containing element which array contains same structures

Tags: c, structure

```
typedef struct Sym_item{
                        char       *name;                       
                        symbolType       type;              
                        char            *data;                      
                        bool             fce;                           
                        TList           *args;                  
                        bool             init;
                        tHTable         *ptr_loctable;  // .. this is conflicting
                        char            *class_name;                
                        bool             isstatic;                  
                        struct Sym_item *nextptr;
}iSymbol;


typedef struct Hash_table{
                        iSymbol         *ptr;
}Hash_item;


typedef Hash_item tHTable[Hash_table_size]; // .............. this is conflicting
```

I am using this structure **`iSymbol`** which contains a **`tHTable`** which is defined lately, but I need it that contains also the array of the symbols as this structure.

This says compiler:

> ```
> error: unknown type name ‘tHTable’<br>
>   tHTable *ptr_loctable;
> ```

Comment: @StoryTeller: Tip: C is not C++.

Comment: @BodoThiesen Tip: Forward declarations work pretty much the same.

Comment: Peter, I also second what Bodo mentions in his answer. Don't typdef everything. Your `struct`s are a heavy thing, and I subscribe to the [school of thought that it should stand out in code](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html).

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes, however a beginner may not be able to understand, what he would have to do in his own code based on what he read there.

Comment: @BodoThiesen, now you see, if you had just said *that* over the snarky tip, I'd have been swayed right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use forward declarations.

Before your iSymbol structure declaration, declare the other structure:

```
struct tHTable;
```

You do not have to write all of it's properties, as this is only a forward declaration.

Comment: tHTable is not a struct

Answer (score 1):

Consider not using `typedef` at all.

If you really want to use `typedef`s, consider defining the `struct`s and `typedef`s independently, like so:

```
struct a { ... }; [...] typedef struct a a_t;
```

In case of forward declarations, that you need here, you have to do this split anyway.

```
struct Hash_table;

struct Sym_item {
    char *name;
    symbolType type;
    char *data;
    bool fce;
    TList *args;
    bool init;
    Hash_item *ptr_loctable[Hash_table_size];
    char *class_name;
    bool isstatic;
    struct Sym_item *nextptr;
};

struct Hash_table {
    struct Sym_item *ptr;
};

typedef struct Sym_item iSymbol;
typedef struct Hash_table Hash_item;
typedef Hash_item tHTable[Hash_table_size];
```